# com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: ' '

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have spent the last hour trying alternate versions of inserting date and time via time stamp into a sql database using java.

```
Date endDate = new Date();    
ptmt.setTimestamp(5, new java.sql.Timestamp(endDate.getTime()));
```

My create table statement is

```
CREATE TABLE Location (
  UserID varchar(50),
  Latitude DOUBLE,
  Longitude DOUBLE,
  Altitude DOUBLE,
  TimeInserted timestamp
);
```

Are there alternative ways of entering the date.

In my prepared statement I tried to have now() within the string, but it looked for the parameter.

```
String queryString = "INSERT INTO Location(UserID,Latitude,Longitude,Altitude,TimeInserted) VALUES(?,?,?,?,now());";
```

however it wasn't happy when searching for the 5th parameter.

Any ideas?

I tried making the table date and managed to insert simply the date - however I need the time to order by.

Thanks

Comment: Why use a `timestamp`? Use a `datetime`.

Comment: I just tried your code with all five (5) parameters and it worked fine for me. There must be something else going on in your code that you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 1):

> however it wasn't happy when searching for the 5th parameter.

```
String queryString = "INSERT INTO Location(UserID,Latitude,Longitude,Altitude,TimeInserted) VALUES(?,?,?,?,now());";
```

Your query string has 4 bound parameters but this statement  `ptmt.setTimestamp(5, new java.sql.Timestamp(endDate.getTime()));`  is trying to bind a `long` to the 5th parameter that doesn't exist

Comment: my query string is actually `String queryString = "INSERT INTO LocationTrace(UserID,Latitude,Longitude,Altitude,TimeInserted) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?);";` i just showed how i tried to use now() in the string like you would in sql.

Answer (score 0):

Things to remember

```
public Timestamp(int year, int month, int date, int hour, int minute, int second, int nano)
```

***Deprecated. instead use the constructor Timestamp(long millis)***

```
Date endDate= new Date();
java.sql.Timestamp eDate = new java.sql.Timestamp(enddate.getTime());
long endDatetime= eDate.getTime();

ptmt.setTimestamp(5, endDatetime);
```

Try this.